# File input using FileInputStream does not work properly

Tags: java, file-io, newline, fileinputstream

The following program should print the `String` "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall,\n Humpty Dumpty had a great fall." to a file and input it back.

```
package io;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class ByteIO {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String output = "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall,\n Humpty Dumpty had a great fall.";
        System.out.println("Output String : " + output);
        try(PrintStream out = new PrintStream("F:\\Test.txt")) {
            out.println(output);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String input = "";
        try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("F:\\Test.txt")) {
            while(in.read() != -1)
                input += (char)in.read();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Input String : " + input);
    }
}
```

However, the `String` I got from the `FileInputStream` was "upyDmt a nawl, upyDmt a  ra al?"! Also, when I opened the file "Test.txt" I found that the output `String` had become "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall, Humpty Dumpty had a great fall." in a single line. Where did the `\n` go?

Comment: The \n is there, but maybe your editor won't show it. Regarding your input: your loop is broken insofar as it delivers only every 2nd character.

Comment: You should close the file between writing and reading from it.

Comment: @JavaNewbie always accept the answer, when you got your solution.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Not required, because I use try-with-resources : The file is automatically closed at the end of the try block.

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 Using try-with will solve this. I would catch the exceptions unles syou are going to do something useful with them.  If you don't catch teh exception, it will print them out anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct solution to my problem :

```
int i = 0;
char c;
    do {
        c = (char)i;
        input += c;
        i = in.read();
    } while(i != -1);
```

The extra space at the front is removed by using a `.trim()` method.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `in.read()` twice:

```
while(in.read() != -1)
    input += (char)in.read();
```

This reads two characters each iteration instead of one, so you are effectively discarding a character each time.

Try storing the character in the while condition, then just adding that character to `input`:

**EDIT: based on JavaNewbie_M107's comment**

```
int i;    
while((i = in.read()) != -1)
   input += (char)i;
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that the `char` c will never return -1, instead, it will keep returning zero, thus setting an infinite loop.

Comment: @JavaNewbie_M107 You are absolutely right, I missed that earlier. I will make an edit.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, Windows (and many applications like Notepad) do not recognize \n as new line. In Windows, \r\n marks a new line. Try opening with a more serious edit program (WordPad should suffice) and you will see it correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

As Hunter said, you need to change your code to this

```
char c;
while((c=in.read()) != -1)
input += c;
```